# HttpURLConnection issue

Tags: java

i am trying to connect a http url.But it shows a "already  connected" exception.
also please find any problem with my basic authentication .

```
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
              .openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

  BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
  String userpassword = user + ":" + password;
  String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(userpassword.getBytes() );
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedAuthorization);
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
  String.valueOf(data.length()));
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www- form-urlencoded");
  conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");
```

Comment: my guess is the second call to conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); Remove it and try.

Comment: Alright, post your complete code and exception stack trace. infact the stacktrace should contain the exact line number

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
 ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
 ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setRequestMethod(POST);
}
```

You can get help from [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=853).